# Generating a pattern on a 4x4 grid

Tags: c

I want to generate a pattern using `C` such that on a 4x4 grid 9 elements should be 1 and the rest 0. The 9 elements should be in groups of 4,3 and 2 such that a group has value 1 either horizontally or vertically. Also, there should be no overlapping of 1's. Following are some examples:

**Example1**

```
1111
1101
0001
0001
```

**Example2**

```
1011
1100
1100
1100
```

but it should not display something like this(overlapping)

```
0111
0100
0100
1100
```

I wrote the following code to generate the above pattern but it mostly fails(`segmentation fault`) or gives the wrong pattern(the 1's overlap):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void pattern(int num, int arr[][4], int checkcol[], int checkrow[]);

int main() {
    int i,j, arr[4][4], checkcol[4], checkrow[4];
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        checkcol[i] = -1;
        checkrow[i] = -1;
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 0;
    }

    for(i=4; i>1; i--)
        pattern(i, arr, checkrow, checkcol);

    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++) {
            printf("%d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void pattern(int n, int arr[][4], int checkcol[], int checkrow[]) {
    int i;
    srand (time(NULL));

    //random number to decide whether to put 1's horizontally or vertically
    int rc = rand()%2;

    //random number to decide to put 1's in which row/column
    int num = rand()%4;

    if(rc) {
            //checks if the column has not already been marked
        if(checkcol[num]!=1) {
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                arr[i][num] = 1;

            checkcol[num] = 1;
        }
        else {
            pattern(n, arr, checkrow, checkcol);
        }
    }
    else {
            //checks if the row has not already been marked
        if(checkrow[num]!=1) {
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                arr[num][i] = 1;

            checkrow[num] = 1;
        }
        else {
            pattern(n, arr, checkrow, checkcol);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because it is infinitely recursively calling `pattern()`. Also there does not seem to be any code that places nine '1's in the matrix. The examples are not that clear as overlap from one row to the next does appear - I guess you meant overlap per row only.

I think the real answer is to rewrite the code. It can be simplified. Just using a 16 element one dimensional array would simplify greatly the coding. Personally I would avoid a recursive solution unless there was a reason for doing so. Of course you may wish to learn this technique.